# Off roading in a desert

Tags: calculation-puzzle, optimization, situation

You’re off-road, in the desert, driving an all-terrain vehicle. You’re $10$ miles off the straight highway, and your destination is $100$ miles ahead, also $10$ miles off the straight highway. You can drive 40 miles per hour off-road, and $80$ miles per hour on the highway. What is the fewest number of minutes in which you can get to your destination?

Comment: Does 100 miles ahead mean 100 miles in the direction of the highway?

Comment: Yeah, it means 100 miles in direction of the highway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two possibilities: either the shortest way does not require traveling along the highway, or it does. Obviously the shortest route that does not use the highway is a straight line, taking 150 minutes.

To find the shortest route with the highway, we find the [critical angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection#Critical_angle). The ratio of the speeds is 1 to 2, so the critical angle is $\arcsin(\frac{1}{2})=30°$ and we need to meet the road at an angle of $90°-30°=60°$. The same applies for when we leave the road at the end:

[image]

The total distance traveled off the road is $2\cdot10\csc(60°)=\frac{40\sqrt3}3$ miles and the total distance traveled along the road is $100-2\cdot10\cot(60°)=100-\frac{20\sqrt3}3$ miles. The total time taken is $15\sqrt3+75\approx101$ minutes.

This is less time than the straight-line route, so it is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 105 minutes

```
10 miles to get to the highway = 10 / 40 * 60 = 15 minutes
100 miles on the highway =  100 / 80 * 60 = 75 minutes
10 miles from the highway to the destination = 10 / 40 * 60 = 15 minutes
Total is 105 minutes
```

Going fully off road would take you 150 minutes (100/40*60) by comparison

Comment: I guess you need to prove it's minimal.